# How to read from DB2 database using perl

Tags: perl, db2, perlscript

Currently i'm trying to create a connection from my windows machine to read from a remote DB2 database and i have to use perl scripting. I'm completely new to perl scripting but it does not seem difficult at all, what i need is some pointers or examples if anyone has of how to do this. Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Have you considered googling for `connect db2 perl`?

Comment: Not sure why people are voting this down I'm just asking a simple question  from a total newbie stand point.

Comment: Because it's a poor question.  Did you bother to read the site help? In particular https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking ?

Answer (score 1):

The basis of all Perl database communication is [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI). In this case, you will also want [DBD::DB2](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::DB2).

Comment: I read about that i'm just absolutely new to perl therefore not entirely sure how i can use it haven't found many good sources.

Comment: The DBI documentation that I linked to is really good. And if you have problems understanding, it contains details of many places to get help with DBI. I suggest you start by setting aside an hour or so to read through that document carefully. If you still have questions after then feel free to ask them here.